# Register External in azure api

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc

I am trying to register external in azure web api but it show error
Object:

> {Message: "Authorization has been denied for this request."}

I used code like this:

```
string realm = "api";
HttpRequestMessage request = new HttpRequestMessage();
request.RequestUri = new Uri("https://api-extranet-physmodo.azurewebsites.net/api/Account/RegisterExternal");
request.Method = HttpMethod.Post;
HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
AuthToken.connectHTTP();
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", AuthToken.PhysmodoToken.access_token.ToString());
HttpResponseMessage response = await client.PostAsync(request.RequestUri, content);
response.Headers.WwwAuthenticate.Add(new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Basic", "realm=\"" + realm + "\""));
response.Content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/json");
return await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
```

How do I register external in this api?